# Sending friend request and adding friends in an iOS social network app using PHP?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, sql, sql-server

Basically, I am now making a basic social network app on iOS platform, using PHP as the backend. I am be able to make the login, register functions in my social network app, however, I am now struggling how to add friend in my app.

As far as I know, I have to make a table for making_friends, just following this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2014/03/facebook-style-friend-request-system.html

However, what I wonder is, if one user send a friend request to another user, then the "status" in the "making_friends" table maybe "0", to indicate that the friend request is sent and waiting for the reply. But how to let the other user know, that a user is sending a friend request to him, and then the other user may accept the friend request and updating the "status" to "1", which means the other user accepts the friend request.

In a word, I am not sure how to communicate from one client to another client, using server as a bridge. Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use push notification to send a request to a client or hit to server periodically and check the status but this is not a good way to handle it

For ios push notification check this [Apple Push Notification Services](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: The push notification will be used when the app is not run. But if the user I want to send friend request is using the app right now, how can I get the device ID of that user and send a message to him? Is there a function in PHP?

Comment: you have to post device id from ios to php page

Answer (score 0):

You can `INSERT` both users as one record in `making_friends` table and make a status for it.

```
 making_friends table
--------------------
User1
User2
Status
```

Once a user inserted in this table you can make a flag on status and let the user know the request

Comment: So how to let the user know there is a friend request sending to him? Should I include the device token or IP address of that particular user?